# How do I get refresh token using GIDSignIn and GTMOAuth2Authentication in iOS?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-plus

I am writing an iOS app that uses Google's GIDSignIn [1] to sign in users and GTLServiceYoutube to execute queries against Youtube (uploading videos and retrieving Youtube video lists).

This works fine when the user first logs in but after approximately one hour, the access token expires and the user is no longer able to execute queries with GTLServiceYoutube due to a 401 error (invalid credentials).

I use the following code to set the GTMOAuth2Authentication after successful login:

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {

    if (error == nil) {
        [self setAuthorizerForSignIn:signIn user:user];
    }
    [super signIn:signIn didSignInForUser:user withError:error];
}

- (void)setAuthorizerForSignIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn user:(GIDGoogleUser *)user {
     GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [[GTMOAuth2Authentication alloc] init];

    [auth setClientID:signIn.clientID];
    [auth setClientSecret:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"GoogleClientSecret"]];
    [auth setUserEmail:user.profile.email];
    [auth setUserID:user.userID];
    [auth setAccessToken:user.authentication.accessToken];
    [auth setRefreshToken:user.authentication.refreshToken];
    [auth setExpirationDate: user.authentication.accessTokenExpirationDate];
    [[UserManager sharedInstance].youTubeService setAuthorizer:auth];
}
```

where `[[UserManager sharedInstance].youTubeService` is an instance of GTLServiceYouTube.

The only problem is with the GTLServiceYouTube. GIDSignIn seems to handle the refresh tokens, so that the user is always logged in after the first login. But the GTLOAuth2Authentication only works on the first login and is broken after one hour.

So my question is: Am I doing something wrong here? Or am I missing something to get the proper access token in GTMOAuth2Authentication after refresh?

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in

Comment: Hi. I have this same problem: after one hour, the token is expired, and GIDSignIn is not refreshing it at all. I discovered that if I terminate the app, and relaunch, it will generate a new token (sometimes this fails as well). And I have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: Google has just recently released an updated version of the Sign-in SDK addressing your issue, hope you like it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the correct way to do this is by signing the user back in when the app is reopened or the token needs to be refreshed. This can be done by calling `[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently]` and then, when it finishes signing in update the keychain or datastore with your new auth tokens.

Answer (score 3):

As of [GoogleSignIn 2.1.0](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn), making a call to `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].signInSilently;` updates the credentials stored in `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication`.

Run `pod update` on your project to update to the 2.1.0 SDK if you're using Cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

With `GTMOAuth2Authentication` you can force a refresh of the auth token with the `authorizeRequest:` method.

From GTMOAuth2Authentication.h

```
// The request argument may be nil to just force a refresh of the access token,
// if needed.

- (void)authorizeRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
       completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))handler;
```

Implementation:

```
// In your sign in method
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] setKeychainName:@"googleAuth"];

// ...

// Retrieving auth and refreshing token
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth;
auth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:@"googleAuth"
                                                             clientID:@"kYourGoogleClientId"
                                                         clientSecret:@"kYourGoogleClientSecret"];

NSLog(@"old auth: %@", auth);

[auth authorizeRequest:nil completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // no auth data or refresh failed
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        // Auth token refresh successful
        NSLog(@"new auth: %@", auth);
    }
}];
```

Comment: The problem is that I am using GIDSignIn and not GPPSignIn and GIDSignIn does not have a setKeychainName method. Do you know how to do the same thing with GIDSignIn?

Comment: @hjortgaard try passing in `nil` for `authForGoogleFromKeychainForName` and see if the method I posted above works.

Comment: Do you mean like this?  `[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:nil ...];` ?

Trying that gives me an error com.google.GTMOAuth2 error -1001.

Comment: Is there anything in the `GIDSignIn` library that allows you to control the keychain or auth data?  I've only used `GPPSignIn` in the past, sorry.

Comment: Not as far as I can see from their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in).

For authentication, there is basically `hasAuthInKeychain` in the `GIDSignIn` class and `accessToken`, `accessTokenExpirationDate`, `refreshToken` and `idToken` in the `GIDAuthentication` class.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It looks like all of the new `GID` types don't map to the older `GPP` types that I have used in my application.  I'll continue to look to see if there is a similar method to `authorizeRequest:` for `GID` objects.